# Possible to restrict the removal of web parts based on permission groups?

Tags: web-part, permissions, web-part-page

As per title. I want to grant only certain permission groups/users the rights to removing a web part from a page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, only users with Full Control, Design or Contribute permission can only add or remove webparts as demonstrated in picture below,

[image]

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx#BM1)

Don't forget about [custom permissions levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot Muhammad. Is it possible to be a lot more granular in the definition of these permissions though? In the sense that I want to evaluate what user belongs to what group and then toggle this permission or not. I don't just want to assume all users with Full Control can add or remove web parts and all others can't. I suppose what I want to do is evaluate whether a user belongs to a group, and then decide whether they can hide a WP or not.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, what's your current group structure for permissions and who you want to give permissions to ? You can create custom permission level with only permission as Add/Remove webparts and assign it to user's you want to be able to add or delete webparts.